# How to push data from Angular form into (array)queue

Tags: javascript, angular

I am wanting to store the form submissions from my Ionic app locally into a queue of some sort to store offline and allow user to submit at a later time popping the form data form the queue. I am having issues accomplishing that:

Form data:

```js
0: Array(1)
0:Location: {ID: "6", Name: "Alto Minerals-Cowden D-27", Lat: "35.8836757", Lon: "-108.3292188", Batch_Treatments: Array(2)}
date: "10-22-2018"
doubleSlug: "No"
notTreated: ""
updatedLocation: {ID: "6", Name: "Alto Minerals-Cowden D-27", Lat: "35.8836757", Lon: "-108.3292188", Batch_Treatments: Array(2)}
1: {gpsLoc: "35.884802254350003,-110.54321959999999"}
2: {md5: "fc9887f481af2a68fece9ca4815796b8"}
3: {appVersion: undefined}
```

When I try to push it to an array I get an error,

> type: "exception", message: "Cannot read property 'push' of null", name: "TypeError"

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I am initializing the data like so:

```
 this.summaryDetails = form.value;
 this.md5Data = md5.appendStr(JSON.stringify(this.summaryDetails)).appendStr(this.lonlat.toString()).appendStr(time.getTime().toString()).end();
 this.submitAllData.push(this.summaryDetails,{'gpsLoc':this.lonlat.toString()},{'md5':this.md5Data},{'appVersion':this.reap.omegaVersion});
 public offlineFormSubmissions:any [] = [];//from service  
 this.offlineFormSubmissions.push(this.submitAllData);//where I am getting error
```

Comment: Share more code since one line code is not enough to trace the issue.

Comment: What exactly are you needing? The form data on top are the values that are assigned to submitAllData variable. And then that variable is what I'm attempting to use to be pushed into the offlineFormSubmissions variable.

Comment: Okay updated, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my issue and unfortunately it was completely my fault. When the app loads, my services localizes all of the variables from local storage and if the local storage was empty it was giving the `offlineFormSubmissions` variable a value of **null**.

So apparently if it is null, I cannot push anything to it and hence why I was getting my error. I created and if statement to handle the variable and now everything works perfectly!